# what & Which android phones are fastest and compatible with ubuntu touch/

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've Been looking at getting an android for Ubuntu and i want to know which phones are compatible if some one could point me to a list of compatible phones i would be happy.i haven't been able to find a phone list anywhere that can give me a list of phones that fully work with Ubuntu touch/phone. all i need is the list but if some one also knows which phone is fastest with it (I'm looking at CPU speed) id be happy to.
so far the ones i have been able to confirm that work are all 1.7Ghz and below but i know there are ones with 2.7 and i want to know if they work, I would assume not since they are all really new and haven't had drivers developed for them.

thanks in advanced for any replies.

Comment: nexus 4 is the only one that is currently officially supported, http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Comment: A list of Phones that aren't fully supported would be nice also.

Comment: there is...https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/

Answer (score -1):

What they all say; Nexus 4, definitely. But a bunch of phones would also work, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 5, Galaxy S3, and a bunch of popular ones, but all of them are not officially supported and can be very buggy.